# delete part of an model in an obj file [solved]

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm really novice when it comes to blender so please be gentle.
I've searched for a possible answer to my question but what I found is years old and didn't worked for me.

I've imported a obj file into blender and it gave me a model, I've selected edit mode and selected a part of the object I want to delete, pressed delete/x and no matter what I select, I cannot get it to delete.

how can I delete a part of an existing object?

for example, I want to delete the end of the submarine
[image]

Comment: Sorry, without any screenshots or anything, maybe the blend file where you tried to do it it is really hard to tell what is going on, because honestly, selecting a part in _Edit Mode_ and hitting `X` or `Del` should do the job and if not, there is some information missing on what kind of object you have there or what you are doing exactly.

Comment: Greetings Gordon,

I've updated the initial post and added a pic, I want to remove the tail part of the submarine

Comment: when I select it, press the left button, I see delete vertices which seems to delete most of the part, so I assume that is the way.

Comment: If you selected it there in this view which I see in the screenshot, it will probably only be the visible part because the backside is hidden from view. In order to select all the occluded vertices as well you have to enable X-Ray mode or switch to Wireframe view.